# My modal not popping up after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I followed the w3schools tutorial for modals https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp but when i click on the button, nothing happens. I've actually followed two previous modal tutorials and on each one, nothing happens when i click the button. I've checked that the external js file is working.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu h4").click(function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("active")
  })
})

//modal 

var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-container');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-btn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="modal-btn"> Click me</button>

<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p> Some text in modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an extra character `>` above the comment `//modal`. Maybe that's causing the issue. Check the browser console, if there's any error, it will be logged on the console. You also need JQuery, so make sure its imported in your code.

Comment: Have you imported the jquery CDN or whatever you are using to fetch jquery?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_bottom the example is working and it's basically your code

Comment: @Yousaf Sorry. That extra character was the stack overflow indent symbol. It is not in my actual code

Comment: @AmoghDixit I have imported Jquery CDN. My website is using some jquery for the navbar and that is working fine.

Comment: @Qchmqs I copied the code from w3schools to make sure it is working. The only thing i changed was that i used GetelementByClassName instead of id. But still no luck

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName returns an object (NodeList) that resembles an array, and doesn't return a single element as you were expecting

getElementById returns a single element, and that's what you should be using for a modal

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu h4").click(function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("active")
  })
})

//modal 

var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-container')[0];

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-btn")[0];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="modal-btn"> Click me</button>

<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p> Some text in modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```